# Is it correct to say that "John is responsible for Mary"?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Is it correct to say that "John is responsible for Mary"?
If not, what should we say?

What I want to denote is a mix of all these senses:

1. Supporting someone, because of sympathy, and also morally
2. Taking care of that person
3. Helping that person
4. Being kind to that person
5. ...

And I have no emphasis on legality.

Comment: Well, for one, the name is spelled Mary, with one r.

Comment: Why do you think it might not be acceptable?

Comment: I think in the context of ELU this is General Reference. It might well pass muster on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), but I'm not going to say it's Off Topic here [***because*** it would be more "On Topic" on ELL](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4249/t)

Comment: You could improve this question by editing it to tell us what you want to express.  Then people could tell you whether this is an acceptable way of expressing that idea.  As it is, people can only really tell you things like "Yes, that sentence is grammatical and makes sense".

Comment: @snailboat, thanks for your feedback. I updated the question.

Comment: '*Takes* responsibility for' might fit 1 and 2, but not 3 and 4. If the concept you want is unclear (like a mixture of four or five ideas, for example) there won't be a clear way to express it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is quite correct to say "John is responsible for Marry" (though the woman's name is much more commonly spelled "Mary").

Without knowing more context, in the US this would tend to mean that John is Mary's guardian in a sort of parent/child sense, or plays some type of oversight role over Mary in a case where she needs guidance. Or it could have a financial sense as well, meaning that perhaps John pays Mary's expenses for some activity.

The context would usually clarify exactly what "John is responsible for Mary" means in each specific setting.

Comment: I'm trying to denote concepts like "supporting somebody", or "helping him", or "taking care of him" and stuff like that. Thanks.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati Well, that's slightly different. To support someone morally is one thing, to support a person financially another. To look after a person is not exactly the same as to be in charge of someone's well being, which *responsible* implies.

Comment: Really? Can't we use the word "responsible" in that context?

Comment: Read the answer carefully, a guardian, an attorney, a parent or even a tutor are said to be *responsible*. They have some form of "legal" recognition or standing. If you're someone's friend you wouldn't normally say you are responsible for their upkeep/well-being/security/education etc. Well, I wouldn't. Perhaps someone else would like to confirm or disagree.